# How can I fix TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Tags: python

I have been getting this error over and over again even with small fixes, it always breaks. I was told to change the variables that contained numbers, into letters ex. Player1 -> PlayerOne. But that still did not fix the TypeError.

I have included the full traceback to further help with finding the issue with the code, requested by another user.

```
What is your username? User1
What is your password? password
Welcome, User1 you have been successfully logged in.
What is your username? User2
What is your password? password
Welcome, User2 you have been successfully logged in.
After this round User1 you now have: 10 Points
After this round User2 you now have: 9 Points
After this round User1 you now have: 13 Points
After this round User2 you now have: 19 Points
After this round User1 you now have: 16 Points
After this round User2 you now have: 26 Points
After this round User1 you now have: 22 Points
After this round User2 you now have: 37 Points
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\corn\Desktop\nea\cs nea.py", line 81, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\corn\Desktop\nea\cs nea.py", line 69, in main
    (playerOne, playerOne_win), (playerTwo, playerTwo_win) = game(userOne, userTwo);
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

```
import random
import time

def login():
    while True:
        username = input('What is your username? ')
        password = input('What is your password? ')
        if username not in ('User1', 'User2', 'User3', 'User4', 'User5'):
            print('Incorrect username or password, try again')
            continue

        if password != 'password':
            print('Incorrect username or password, try again')
            continue

        print(f'Welcome, {username} you have been successfully logged in.')
        return username

def roll():
    dieOne = random.randint(1, 6)
    dieTwo = random.randint(1, 6)
    points = dieOne + dieTwo
    if dieOne == dieTwo:
        points += random.randint(1, 6)
    return points

def game(userOne, userTwo):
    playerOne_points = 0
    playerTwo_points = 0
    for i in range(1,5):
        playerOne_points += roll()
        print(f'After this round {userOne} you now have: {playerOne_points} Points')
        time.sleep(1)
        playerTwo_points += roll()
        print(f'After this round {userTwo} you now have: {playerTwo_points} Points')
        time.sleep(1)

    playerOne_tiebreaker = 0
    playerTwo_tiebreaker = 0
    if playerOne_points == playerTwo_tiebreaker:
        while playerOne_tiebreaker == playerTwo_tiebreaker:
            playerOne_tiebreaker = random.randint(1,6)
            playerTwo_tiebreaker = random.randint(1,6)

def add_winner(winner):
    file = open('Winner.txt', 'a')
    file.write('{winner[0]},{winner[1]}\n')

def get_leaderboard():
    file = open('Leaderboard.txt', 'r')
    return [line.replace('\n','') for line in file.readlines()]

def save_leaderboard(leaderboard):
    with open('Leaderboard.txt', 'w'):
        for item in leaderboard:
            file.write(f'{item}\n')
            file.close(winner)

def main():
    userOne = login()
    userTwo = login()
    (playerOne, playerOne_win), (playerTwo, playerTwo_win) = game(userOne, userTwo);
    if playerOne_win:
        winner = (playerOne, userOne)
    else:
        winner = (playerTwo, userTwo)
    print('Well done, {userOne} you won with {playerOne_points} Points')
    add_winner(winner)
    leaderboard = get_leaderboard()
    save_leaderboard(leaderboard)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: And limit the post to a single question. You need a [mcve]

Comment: ***"TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object"***: You didn't return a explicit value from  `def game(...`, therefore `NoneType` which is the default got returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning anything from the game() function making the call to game(userOne, userTwo) throw the NoneType error back in:

```
(playerOne, playerOne_win), (playerTwo, playerTwo_win) = game(userOne, userTwo);
```

Just add a line at the end of the function with: 
`return (playerOne, playerOne_win), (playerTwo, playerTwo_win)` replacing those names for the correct variables inside that function.

Comment: I've plugged in:

return (playerOne, playerOne_win), (playerTwo, playerTwo_win)

at the end of the main function, and it still outputs the same error

Comment: Did you replace playerOne and playerOne_win for the corresponding variables in the function? I think you want to return (userOne, True),(userTwo, False) if userOne wins. Can you clarify a bit more what the game() function is trying to return? I'm confused about the difference between playerOne and userOne

Comment: Also playerOne_points is not in scope in main so you won't be able to print it inside print(). And you won't be able to print it anyways if you don't add an f at the start of the string as in ```print(f'blabla{playerOne_points}')```. More info on this: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Comment: Looking at your code a bit more I think you want to ```return (playerOne_points, playerOne_win), (playerTwo_points, playerTwo_win)``` so that the points come into the main scope and you can print them. All you need to do is define the win variables depending on who won in game(). You're not using playerOne nor playerTwo again in main() so I assume they are the same as userOne and userTwo.

Comment: I've just realised you said you tried to return (playerOne, playerOne_win), (playerTwo, playerTwo_win) at the end of main. I'm saying you have to return them from game().

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thanks for helping me realise where I put your code in wrong, I've tested it and a new error came up, I can fix this error now. Thank you so much for helping!